# How to understand bash -c " echo $S " = bash -c " echo '$S ' " = bash -c " echo "$S" " = echo "$S" = echo $S

Tags: linux, bash

Set

`S=2`

then,

`echo $S` = `echo "$S"`=

`bash -c " echo $S "` =
`bash -c " echo '$S' "` =
`bash -c " echo "$S" "`

---

---

the most confusing one for me is `bash -c " echo '$S' "`

since `echo '$S'` = `$S`

How `bash -c " echo '$S' "` works like others?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: I guess if you weren't surprised, you wouldn't ask. The output of which commands surprised you? What else did you expect from these commands and why?

Comment: Homework? Is there more context you could provide, and maybe edit the question to something more specific. Are you trying to make a shell script. All of the `echo` commands are different ways of doing the same thing, outputting the value of the `S` variable to `stdout`, normally the terminal display.

Comment: @Brain Sorry about that, I just added more specific question. Actually I would add more but I couldn't, my brain is burning, it's so struggling for me to even ask..

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for your reference, I have looked up on that for couple of times before, I ddin't  get what I asked, or those answers are still too hard to understand for me. Thanks anyway.